# How to get a string from asp.net webservice in sql server 2008 and split the string

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I get a string as input parameter for my SP coming from asp.net web service (I have already created).

The input string is not fixed i.e., it may have a variable length, and i want the *unknown* string to be split by my `store procedure` and its content inserted into respective columns in table. My string sample is as follows:

`date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8`

...and so on.
Many thanks

Comment: Are you planning to produce insert statements to more that one table?

Comment: Why are you asking this again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggle with this every day because some programmer thought they were being awesome by creating their own custom multi-delimited format years ago. It's non-standard. It's slow. Custom programming has to be duplicated (and debugged) on every system that works with this data. Frankly, it is terrible, and there's no compelling reason it had to be that way.

Since you have control over what the web service does, I suggest passing XML from your web service to SQL Server. SQL Server 2008 has many great ways to work with XML, as do many data platforms, libraries, and programming languages. None of them have built-in capabilities to deal with your custom serialization format.